# Tengo problemas para emular en Xamarin.form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Acabo de instalar Visual Studio con Xamarin para Tizen, pero tengo el problema de no poder emular.
[image: Error al depurar proyecto]

Comment: por defecto tienes habilitado que ejecute el proyecto de librería de clases cosa que eso no se puede ejecutar, te lo dice en el mensaje. El otro proyecto que tienes, dale botón derecho y le das en la opción **Establecer como proyecto de inicio**